# Prefix queries (*) in Azure Search don't return expected results

Tags: odata, azure-cognitive-search

While searching on azure using Rest API provided by [Microsoft Search API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents)
Not behaving correctly when search string contains '@'.

Example: I've 3 rows in Azure Document
CES
CES@123
CES@1234

When My search string was CES* then all 3 were the result.
When My Search string was CES@123* then only one exact matching record was in result.
When My Search string was CES@* then there was no result.

As per my requirement in case of "CES@*" search string, all 3 records should be part of result set.

I've tried " "(space) in replacement of @ it works, but my data contains @ for search I need to maintain this.

I'm using SearchMode:Any.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is expected.

Query terms of prefix queries are not analyzed. Therefore, in your example with "CES@*" you are searching for term *CES@* while the *@* sign was stripped from the terms in the index: CES, 123, 1234.

Here is an excerpt from the [How full text search works in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture) article:

> Exceptions to lexical analysis
>
> Lexical analysis applies only to query types that require complete
>   terms – either a term query or a phrase query. It doesn’t apply to
>   query types with incomplete terms – prefix query, wildcard query,
>   regex query – or to a fuzzy query. Those query types, including the
>   prefix query with term air-condition* in our example, are added
>   directly to the query tree, bypassing the analysis stage. The only
>   transformation performed on query terms of those types is lowercasing.