# Need help on Azure search with search term having asterisk(*)

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

We are facing an issue with Azure search API when hit with search term with asterisk(*) at the end and also with special characters.

We are hitting our production Azure search API with below json object and get no results. Notice the search term "déménage*" with asterisk(*) at the end.

https://one-adscope-search-fr-prod.search.windows.net/indexes/one-adscope-advancedsearch-fr/docs/search?api-version=2016-09-01

```
{
  "count": "true",
  "facets": null,
  "orderby": "firstSeenDate desc,creativeIdNumber asc",
  "search": "déménage*",
  "searchFields": "keywordSignatureLangSearch,keywordSloganLangSearch,keywordTextLangSearch,keywordScriptLangSearch,keywordIncrustTVLangSearch,keywordVisualKeywordsLangSearch,keywordAgencyLangSearch,keywordMusicTitleLangSearch,keywordMusicPerformerLangSearch,keywordMusicAuthorLangSearch,categoryLevel_1_nameLangSearch,categoryLevel_2_nameLangSearch,categoryLevel_3_nameLangSearch,categoryLevel_4_nameLangSearch,categoryLevel_5_nameLangSearch,productLevel_1_nameLangSearch,productLevel_2_nameLangSearch,productLevel_3_nameLangSearch,productLevel_4_nameLangSearch,productLevel_5_nameLangSearch,campaignNamesLangSearch,themeNamesLangSearch,creativeTitleLangSearch,visualLangSearch,keyword_tagsLangSearch,countryNameLangSearch,directorLangSearch,hashtagsLangSearch,illustratorLangSearch,inlayLangSearch,csmediaNameLangSearch,subMediaNameLangSearch,modifVersionLangSearch,photographerLangSearch,productionLangSearch,taglineLangSearch,partnersLangSearch,creativeLabelLangSearch,propertyNameLangSearch,sponsorshipProgramTitleLangSearch",
  "searchMode": "any",
  "select": "",
  "skip": 0,
  "top": 250,
  "queryType": "full"
}
```

But when hit the API with similar json except only one change – search term without and asterisk(*) at the end like "déménage” we are getting appropriate results.

Please notice below all the other fields are the same along with SearchFields.

```
{
  "count": "true",
  "facets": null,
  "orderby": "firstSeenDate desc,creativeIdNumber asc",
  "search": "déménage",
  "searchFields": "keywordSignatureLangSearch,keywordSloganLangSearch,keywordTextLangSearch,keywordScriptLangSearch,keywordIncrustTVLangSearch,keywordVisualKeywordsLangSearch,keywordAgencyLangSearch,keywordMusicTitleLangSearch,keywordMusicPerformerLangSearch,keywordMusicAuthorLangSearch,categoryLevel_1_nameLangSearch,categoryLevel_2_nameLangSearch,categoryLevel_3_nameLangSearch,categoryLevel_4_nameLangSearch,categoryLevel_5_nameLangSearch,productLevel_1_nameLangSearch,productLevel_2_nameLangSearch,productLevel_3_nameLangSearch,productLevel_4_nameLangSearch,productLevel_5_nameLangSearch,campaignNamesLangSearch,themeNamesLangSearch,creativeTitleLangSearch,visualLangSearch,keyword_tagsLangSearch,countryNameLangSearch,directorLangSearch,hashtagsLangSearch,illustratorLangSearch,inlayLangSearch,csmediaNameLangSearch,subMediaNameLangSearch,modifVersionLangSearch,photographerLangSearch,productionLangSearch,taglineLangSearch,partnersLangSearch,creativeLabelLangSearch,propertyNameLangSearch,sponsorshipProgramTitleLangSearch",
  "searchMode": "any",
  "select": "",
  "skip": 0,
  "top": 250,
  "queryType": "full"
}
```

Please advise at the earliest.

Thanks,
Bhavik Shah

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the documents returned in the case without the suffix operator '*' are matching because the diacritics were removed from the search term during the lexical analysis process. Please see this post for details: [Prefix queries (*) in Azure Search don't return expected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43917814/prefix-queries-in-azure-search-dont-return-expected-results)

Consider changing your query to  search=déménage* OR déménage